# curl localhost server in terminal get empty reply but postman and chrome get the response

Tags: curl

I implemented a server with Go package `net/http` and `localhost:8888/status` should return some json like `{"Count":0,"KeySize":0,"ValueSize":0}`.

I did get the json in Chrome and Postman, but `curl http://localhost:8888/status` and `curl localhost:8888/status` returned `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`.

`curl` works fine while visiting other sites like `curl www.google.com`.

`curl -v localhost:8888` returned

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* SOCKS5 communication to localhost:8888
* SOCKS5 connect to IPv6 ::1 (locally resolved)
* SOCKS5 request granted.
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 1086 (#0)
> GET /status HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8888
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I have no idea whether there is a bug in my site code or something is wrong with my curl. btw, I uses shadowsocks as proxy in my terminal.

Comment: I have having the same problem. Did you solved it?

Comment: It has been long since that. Maybe we can solve it again if you provide more information, like your code for test.

Comment: I finally solved my issue. It was related to Itellij IDE when was starting up a springboot service sometimes left the service on the port raised blocked. After killing the service, port was responding correctly with curl and postman

Answer (score 0):

Can you compare the request headers curl is sending vs what you might be sending in postman? It is possible that your server might only be sending the json response only to requests containing certain type of headers.

Comment: I tried using the same headers with postman, but curl still returned empty